# How can you show multiple alert dialogs, one after the other, in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

The following code shows a "Delete file" button. When the user presses it, a confirmation alert dialog appears. When the user presses "Delete" on that first dialog, I want to show a second alert dialog confirming that the file has been deleted. However, it never shows up, even though debugging the code confirmed that the second "return Alert..." statement is actually being executed as expected. Is there a way to make the second alert show up too?

```
import SwiftUI

enum alertShownType {
    case alertNone, alertDeleteFile,alertFileDeleted
}

struct ContentView: View {

    @State var showingAlert = false
    @State var alertShown: alertShownType = alertShownType.alertNone

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.alertShown = alertShownType.alertDeleteFile
            self.showingAlert = true
        })
        {
            Text("Delete file")
        }.padding(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 10, trailing:0))
        .alert(isPresented: $showingAlert, content: {
            if (alertShown == alertShownType.alertDeleteFile)
            {
                return Alert(title: Text("Delete file"),
                      message: Text("Are you sure?"),
                      primaryButton: .destructive(Text("Delete")) {

                        // Delete the file

                        ....

                        // Show the next alert
                        alertShown = alertShownType.alertFileDeleted
                        showingAlert = true
                      },
                      secondaryButton: .cancel())
            }
            else // alertFileDeleted
            {
                return Alert(title: Text("File deleted"), message:
                            Text("Done!"),
                      dismissButton: .default(Text("OK")))
            }
        })
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but that does not help. I can already show multiple different Alerts from a single page of my app, using the enum values. The problem is how to show a second alert from *within* the action of the first alert when the primary button is pressed.

Answer (score 2):

You just need

```
public func alert<Item>(item: Binding<Item?>, content: (Item) -> Alert)
```

Not required `@State var showingAlert = false` flag.

Setup you code like this

```
enum alertShownType : Identifiable {
    case alertNone,
    alertDeleteFile,
    alertFileDeleted

    var id : Int { get {
        hashValue
    }}
}

struct ContentViewAlerts: View {

    @State var alertShown: alertShownType?
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.alertShown = alertShownType.alertDeleteFile
        })
        {
            Text("Delete file")
        }.padding(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 10, trailing:0))
        .alert(item: $alertShown, content: { alertType in
            if (alertShown == alertShownType.alertDeleteFile)
            {
                return Alert(title: Text("Delete file"),
                             message: Text("Are you sure?"),
                             primaryButton: .destructive(Text("Delete")) {
                                
                                // Delete the file
                                
                                //                                ....
                                
                                // Show the next alert
                                alertShown = alertShownType.alertFileDeleted
                             },
                             secondaryButton: .cancel())
            }
            else // alertFileDeleted
            {
                return Alert(title: Text("File deleted"), message:
                                Text("Done!"),
                             dismissButton: .default(Text("OK")))
            }
        })
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: That's great. Thanks!

Just one additional change was required. The enum needed to be "Identifiable". I've edited your answer to include this new enum.

Comment: @Ant yes I just forget to add. Thanks.